# Laravel - how to handle not required/optional field in $fillable insert and update

Tags: laravel, model, fillable

I have table with below fields.

Only **name** is required and rest of them is optional

`'name','no_of_color','offset_printing_rate','screen_printing_rate','positive_rate','regular_plate_rate','big_plate_rate',`

**My model**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'no_of_color',
        'offset_printing_rate',
        'screen_printing_rate',
        'positive_rate',
        'regular_plate_rate',
        'big_plate_rate',
    ];
```

but when I don't fill optional field it returns error

> SQL: insert into table_name (`name`, `no_of_color`, `offset_printing_rate`, `screen_printing_rate`, `positive_rate`, `regular_plate_rate`, `big_plate_rate`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (name, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2021-10-09 14:47:36, 2021-10-09 14:47:36)

Comment: So you need to check yourself if those fields are empty or not and adjust your query accordingly

Comment: Are you sure you've added `->nullable()` to optional fields in the migration?

Comment: does validation rule **nullable** will work in this situation ? @brombeer

Comment: @Nicola, yes i did ``$table->string('no_of_color',255)->nullable();`` ``$table->float('offset_printing_rate',8,2)->default(0);`` . no_of_color is string and other optional filed are numeric.

Comment: Ok, so as @brombeer said you need to adjust the query. You can add the code where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL always want a value to all cols so in laravel you have to set default for each col or set it nullable but for performance purpose, i recommended you to split optional in other table and connect them to main table by relation this will prevent increasing of null  records so you don't have to waste your host space